# Get log file error using correlation id

Tags: sharepoint-server

I get an error message when I execute Merge-SPLogFile using Sharepoint 2019 Management Shell
you can find below my error message
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following powershell to check if your Timer Job-Instances are down in specific servers:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$FarmTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instances
foreach ($FT in $FarmTimers)
{
   write-host "Server: " $FT.Server.Name.ToString();
   write-host "Status: " $FT.status;
   write-host "Allow Service Jobs: " $FT.AllowServiceJobs;
   write-host "Allow Content DB Jobs: " $FT.AllowContentDatabaseJobs;"`n"
}
```

If you have any server showing disabled status, start it in the dedicated server using below powershell:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$FarmTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instances
foreach ($FT in $FarmTimers)
{
   write-host "Server: " $FT.Server.Name.ToString();
   write-host "Status: " $FT.status;
   write-host "Allow Service Jobs: " $FT.AllowServiceJobs;
   write-host "Allow Content DB Jobs: " $FT.AllowContentDatabaseJobs;"`n"
}
$disabledTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instances | where {$_.Status -ne "Online"}
if ($disabledTimers -ne $null)
{
   foreach ($timer in $disabledTimers)
   {
      Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Timer service instance on server " $timer.Server.Name " is NOT Online. Current status:" $timer.Status
      Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Attempting to set the status of the service instance to online..."
      $timer.Provision()
      $timer.Start()
      write-host -ForegroundColor Red "You MUST now go restart the SharePoint timer service on server " $FT.Server.Name}}
   else
   {
      Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "All Timer Service Instances in the farm are online. No problems found!"
}
```

More information for your reference:

https://guidesharepoint.wordpress.com/2019/02/28/warning-unable-to-start-job-collectlogfiles-on-server-sharepoint/

Comment: this solution worked for me